# Как извлечь изображение из ресурсов динамически созданного exe

Tags: c#

Разбирался с CodeDomProvider, написал билдер по статье из интернета. Решил при создании exe добавлять в него файл ресурсов, в который предварительно загружал Png рисунок.
Создавал файл ресурсов и загружал его в параметры создаваемого exe так:

```
CodeDomProvider compiler = new CSharpCodeProvider();
CompilerParameters Params = new CompilerParameters();

var rwritter = new ResourceWriter("res.resource");
rwritter.AddResource("ii", new Bitmap("image.png"));
rwritter.Generate();
rwritter.Close();

Params.EmbeddedResources.Add("res.resource");
compiler.CompileAssemblyFromSource(Params, result);
```

Файл ресурсов успешно помещается в созданный билд. Картинка так же успешно загружается в файл ресурсов. В самой забилденной программе пытаюсь отобразить картинку на PictureBox с помощью ResourceManager

```
try
{
   ResourceManager rm = new ResourceManager("res", typeof(Form1).Assembly);
   Bitmap bmp = (Bitmap)rm.GetObject("ii");
   pictureBox1.BackgroundImage = bmp;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
   MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
```

При запуске билда выдает ошибку: "Не удалось найти ресурсы, соотвутствующие указанной культуре или нейтральной культуре. Проверьте правильность внедрения или связывания "res.resources" со сборкой "build"...".

[image: Ошибка при запуске билда]

Как это можно пофиксить? Раскурил несколько статей на MSDN - вроде делаю все правильно, но мне все равно выдает эту ошибку.
В том что файл ресурсов был создан успешно можно убедиться посмотрев через dnSpy:
[image: Созданный билд открытый в dnSpy]

Comment: замените res.resource -> res.resource**s** в коде билдера

Comment: Чувствую себя каким-то опущенным дураком. Все оказалось настолько просто. Спасибо)